# DataInputStream.available() como usarla debidamente

Tags: java, poo, socket, class, server

Tengo una clase Servidor que me está lanzando una serie de mensajes como String.
Con la clase cliente quiero recoger todos esos mensajes con un bucle while y mostrarlos por consola con un System.out.println.

He escribo el siguiente código:

```
if (siguientePaso) {
    System.out.println("Paso final");
    Integer opcion = 0;

    while (opcion < 3) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("******** MENÚ *********");
        System.out.println("1. VER DIRECTORIO");
        System.out.println("2. VER ARCHIVO");
        System.out.println("3. SALIR");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Eliga una opción: ");
        opcion = s.nextInt();
        
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                datosSalida.writeInt(opcion);
                while(datosEntrada.available() > 0){
                    mensajeServidorTexto = datosEntrada.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(mensajeServidorTexto);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Gracias por utilizar nuestro Software.");
}
```

Pero no me escupe nada por pantalla. En la clase Servidor tengo el siguiente código:

```
if(logIn){
    mensajeClienteNumero = datosEntrada.readInt();
    
    switch(mensajeClienteNumero){
        case 1:
            fichero = new File(".");
            File[] archivos = fichero.listFiles();
            for(int i=0; i<archivos.length; i++){
                System.out.println(archivos[i].getName());
                datosSalida.writeUTF(archivos[i].getName());
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? No se como utilizar la función available.

Comment: Nota que `Integer` es una clase e `int` es un tipo primitivo. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5199425/13419694

Comment: @Mateo gracias por la info. Usaba clases porque me parecía que podía hacer operaciones de una forma más sencilla. Pero lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima.

Comment: He conseguido solucionar el problema aunque no se la razón y por eso no lo hago como respuesta. Si antes del bucle while escribo: 'datosEntrada.readUTF();' o lo muestro por un System.out.println (dependiendo de lo que me interese en ese instante, el bucle while funciona.